# Getting the Header Values visible in SortableTableView in ISchwarz23's library

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I've tried to use [this library](https://github.com/ISchwarz23/SortableTableView) to get a table view but when i try to do so using the below code, the table headers are not shown at all. Can someone please offer me a helping hand here..

```
    TableView tableView = (TableView) findViewById(R.id.tableView);
    tableView.setColumnCount(4);
    tableView.setHeaderAdapter(new SimpleTableHeaderAdapter(this,"Header", "is", "not","visible!"));
    tableView.setDataAdapter(new SimpleTableDataAdapter(this,DATA_TO_SHOW));
```

[image: screenshot of the current implementation]

Comment: @Ingo Schwarz Little help here please

Answer (score 1):

Try download [the Latest release - SortableTableView v2.5.0](https://github.com/ISchwarz23/SortableTableView/archive/v2.5.0.zip)